# Função JavaScript não funcionando corretamente

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, possuo a função abaixo javascript para realizar a conta quando sair do campo desconto:

```js
function calcular1() {
  String.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
    var v = this;

    if (v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
      v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
    }

    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)([\d]{3}),([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2,$3");

    return v;
  };
  var v1 = document.getElementById("txtValoraPagar").value;
  var v2 = document.getElementById("txtDesconto").value;
  var txtTotalPagar = document.getElementById("txtTotalPagar");
  if ((v2.replace("R$", "").replace(",", ".").replace(/\s*/g, '')) > (v1.replace(",", ".").replace(/\s*/g, ''))) {
    alert('Valor do desconto não pode ser maior do que o valor a receber.');
    document.getElementById("txtDesconto").value = '';
    return false;
  }
  if ((v1 != "") && (v2 != "") && (v1.replace(",", ".").replace(/\s*/g, '') >= v2.replace("R$", "").replace(",", ".").replace(/\s*/g, ''))) {
    txtTotalPagar.value = (eval(v1.replace(",", ".") - eval(v2.replace("R$", "").replace(",", "."))));
    txtTotalPagar.value = 'R$ ' + String(txtTotalPagar.value).formatMoney();
  }
```

Por exemplo, se o valor é 15,00 e o desconto é de 5,00 ele entra como se o desconto fosse maior que o valor, e informa o alert. Agora se o valor é 15,00 e coloco o desconto de 1,00, ele funciona, e mostra o valor total a pagar certo, de 14,00. Pelo oq da para entender, ele esta fazendo a conta do primeiro numero do 15, q é 1, e pega o 5. Não sei porque isso está ocorrendo.

Comment: O resultado como você está descrevendo está correto porque você está comparando instâncias de caracteres e não de números.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que fazer a comparação de números ao invés de caracteres.

Só mais outra coisa, coloque o nome das suas variáveis mais intuitivas. Não pode ter variável com nome v1, v2. O que elas significam? Fica mais claro variáveis com nome 'valor' e 'desconto' que são o que elas realmente representam.

```js
function calcular2() {
   var txtValor = document.getElementById("txtValoraPagar").value;
   var txtDesconto = document.getElementById("txtDesconto").value;
   var txtTotalPagar = document.getElementById("txtTotalPagar");
   var valor =0;
   var desconto =0; 
   if(txtValor != null)
     valor = Number(txtValor.replace(/[R\$ ]/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
   if(txtDesconto != null)
     desconto = Number(txtDesconto.replace(/[R\$ ]/g, '').replace(',', '.'));
   if(desconto > valor){
     alert('Valor do desconto não pode ser maior do que o valor a receber.');
     return false;
   }else if (valor >= desconto){
     txtTotalPagar.value = 'R$ ' + (valor - desconto);
   } 
}
```

```html
Valor: <input type="text" id="txtValoraPagar" value="R$ ">
<br>
Desconto: <input type="text" id="txtDesconto" value="R$ ">
<br>
Total: <input type="text" id="txtTotalPagar" readonly="true" placeholder="Valor final">
<br>
<button onclick="calcular2()">Calcular</button>
```

Comment: Ele funciona, porém quando o valor passa de mil, que aparece o ponto, por exemplo: 5.000,00, ele não faz nenhuma ação.

Comment: Esse 'ponto' é normal para o padrão de apresentação numérico. Ele sempre aparece de 3 em 3 casas. Por exemplo: 1.000 ou 1.000.000

Comment: Sim, mas quando aparece o ponto, ele não entra na função, nada acontece.

Comment: Ao invés de /[R\$ ]/g como REGEX, use /[R\$ \.]/g que vai funcionar

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado.

Comment: Outra coisa que você pode fazer é ao inves de usar <input type="text"> usar o <input type="number">. Assim você não vai mais se preocupar com regex, pois o campo já retornará um número quando ele for requisitado. Fiz o exemplo com <input type="text"> para ficar igual ao que você já estava fazendo e também por não saber se isso atenderia o seu propósito.